# Php If else statment

Tags: php, if-statement

Am i doing something wrong here, the return value is not right, just returns else part..

i want to check the input value is greater or equal and lesser or equal as the condition show below, is this the right way to do it or am i doing it wrong...

```
$tornadoball = 22;
$tornadoVal = "";
$tornadoScore = "";

if ( $tornadoball <= 20 && $tornadoball >= 29): {
    $tornadoScore = 0.25;
}

elseif ( $tornadoball <= 30 && $tornadoball >= 34): {
    $tornadoScore = 0.50;
}

elseif ( $tornadoball <= 35 && $tornadoball >= 39 ): {
    $tornadoScore = 0.75;
}

elseif ( $tornadoball >= 40 ): {
    $tornadoScore = 1.00;
}

else: {
    echo " Value";
}

endif;

$tornadoVal == floatval($tornadoScore);

echo $tornadoVal;
```

Comment: "is this the right way" --- does it work as you expect?

Comment: Lose the colon characters (`:`). Your conditionals should look like `if (condition) { statement } elseif (condition) { statement }`

Comment: Enable error_reporting in the php.ini, then fix the syntax.

Comment: You should learn C before PHP

Comment: @true: and assembly before C, and microelectronics before assembly...

Comment: Another point; your logic seems way off. Take the first condition as an example. `if (val <= 20 && val >= 29)`. This is an impossible condition. It will **always** be `false`

Comment: @true: the point is - it makes little to nothing sense in "should learn C before PHP". Knowing C will barely make you a good php developer.

Comment: Also most of your conditions can never be true. How can a number be <= 20 and >= 29 at the same time.  If you wanted to check if the number is between 20 and 29 you need to do. X >= 20 and x <= 29.   The way your conditionals are laid out it will always be else unless it is >= 40 as the rest of the conditions cannot be true.

Comment: @doon i guess you are right, i was just wondering about that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you mean `>= min` and `<= max`, (in betweens):

```
$tornadoball = 22;
$tornadoScore = 0;

if($tornadoball >= 20 && $tornadoball <= 29) { // if this number is in between 20 to 29
    $tornadoScore = 0.25;
}
elseif($tornadoball >= 30 && $tornadoball <= 34) { // if this number is in between 30 to 34
    $tornadoScore = 0.50;
}
elseif($tornadoball >= 35 && $tornadoball <= 39 ) { // if this number is in between 35 to 39
    $tornadoScore = 0.75;
}
elseif($tornadoball >= 40 ) { // if this number is greater than 40
    $tornadoScore = 1.00;
}
else {
    echo 'did not meet any criteria';
}

var_dump($tornadoScore);
```

Comment: @Phil because it's not written in C presumably

Comment: Hey @Phill. I accidently down-voted this. (I've since taken it away). Also zerkms. Presumably means you have factual, one could say empirical evidence that something is true. In this case you would be assuming it was down-voted because it is not written in C. You had no evidence expect your intuition. The correct word to use, in this case, would be some derivation of "assume"

Comment: Oh I was right, that's because it's not in C

Comment: I'm _assuming_ (assume because I don't have proof) English is not your first language. Before using big words like "presumably", please make sure you are using it in the correct context :)

Comment: @true: I (with my terrible english) at least don't give advices that don't make much sense ;-P

Comment: @ghost: this working exactly as i had hoped for... thanks a lot. could u please explain me where i was going wrong, that would be a lot of help

Comment: you checking logic is a bit off, starting in the first if. you're trying to check a number if 22 is less than or equal to 20 and 22 is greater than or equal to 29. doesn't make sense. i made some comments on the answer check it to shed some light

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to write `:` or `endif;` !

This should work:

```
<?php
    $tornadoball = 22;
    $tornadoVal = "";
    $tornadoScore = "";

    if ( $tornadoball <= 20 && $tornadoball >= 29) 
    {
      $tornadoScore = 0.25; 
    } 
    elseif ( $tornadoball <= 30 && $tornadoball >= 34) 
    {
        $tornadoScore = 0.50;

    } 
    elseif ( $tornadoball <= 35 && $tornadoball >= 39 ) 
    {
        $tornadoScore = 0.75;

    } 
    elseif ( $tornadoball >= 40 ) 
    {
        $tornadoScore = 1.00;
    } 
    else
    {
        echo " Value";
    }

    $tornadoVal == floatval($tornadoScore);

    echo $tornadoVal;

?>
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to advice a newbie omit `{` and `}`s

Answer (score 1):

change this line of code

```
if ( $tornadoball <= 20 && $tornadoball >= 29):
```

to this one

```
 if ( $tornadoball <= 20 && $tornadoball >= 29)
```

remove the colon 
and remove the

```
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and **read the comment in the answer ass well

**Second** **Most of your condition will never be met. So I changed them have a look**

```
<?php $tornadoball = 22;
$tornadoVal = "";
$tornadoScore = "";
//Below if condition is wrong
if ( $tornadoball >= 20 && $tornadoball <= 29): {
$tornadoScore = 0.25;
}

elseif ( $tornadoball >= 30 && $tornadoball <= 34): {
$tornadoScore = 0.50;
}

elseif ( $tornadoball >= 35 && $tornadoball <= 39 ): {
$tornadoScore = 0.75;
}

elseif ( $tornadoball >= 40 ): {
$tornadoScore = 1.00;
}

else: {
echo " Value";
}

endif;

$tornadoVal = floatval($tornadoScore);
//You got two equal, two equal are comparistion operator
//use one equal. Thats assignment operator

echo $tornadoVal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please check with the below code..Is this what you are expecting output..

```
$tornadoball = 22;
$tornadoVal = "";
$tornadoScore = "";

if (($tornadoball <= 20) || ($tornadoball >= 29)) 
{
    $tornadoScore = 0.25;
}

else if (($tornadoball <= 30) ||($tornadoball >= 34)) 
{
    $tornadoScore = 0.50;
}

else if (($tornadoball <= 35) || ($tornadoball >= 39)) 
{
    $tornadoScore = 0.75;
}

else if ($tornadoball >= 40 )
{
    $tornadoScore = 1.00;
}

else 
{
    $tornadoScore= " Value";
}


$tornadoVal = floatval($tornadoScore);

echo $tornadoScore;
```

Comment: sorry! no luck, i guess the whole logic of mine may be wrong

Comment: Can you say me the what is the output value you are guessing

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// initialization
$tornadoball = 22;
$tornadoVal = "";
$tornadoScore = "";

//Below if condition is wrong
if ( $tornadoball >= 20 && $tornadoball <= 29) {
$tornadoScore = 0.25;
}

elseif ( $tornadoball <= 30 && $tornadoball >= 34) {
$tornadoScore = 0.50;
}

elseif ( $tornadoball <= 35 && $tornadoball >= 39 ) {
$tornadoScore = 0.75;
}

elseif ( $tornadoball >= 40 ) {
$tornadoScore = 1.00;
}
else {
// do nothing
}

echo "Score Value = " . $tornadoScore;

$tornadoVal = floatval($tornadoScore);
//You got two equal, two equal are comparistion operator
//use one equal. Thats assignment operator

echo "<br>";
echo "Tornado Value = " . $tornadoVal;
?>
```